# Type inference:The initializer in the declaration is used to drive the inference engine,and is required

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Type inference:The intializer in the declaration is used to drive the inference engine,and is required.The following are thus illegal:

```
var obj2    ://ERROR :must have an intializer
var obj3=null   :ERROR   :must have a specific type
```

Assuming the inference is successful,the inferred type becomes permanent and compilation proceeds as usual,Apparent misuses of the type are detected and reported by the compiler:

```
var obj4 ="hi!";
obj4.Close();//Oops,wrong object!(Error:'string does not contain' 'Close')
```

Do not confuse var with the concept of a VB varient(its not),nor with the concept of var in dynamic languages like javascript(where var really means object).in these languages the variable's type can change nad so type checking is performed at runtime increased flexibility at the cost of safety.in c# 3.0 the type cannot  change and all type checking is done at compile-time.For example,if the inferred type is object(as for obj6 below),in c# 3.0 you end up with an obect reference of vaery little functionality:

```
object obj5="hi"; //obj5 references the string "hi!",but type is object
var obj6    =obj5; //obj6 also references "hi!",with inferred type object
.
.
.

string si=obj6.ToUpper(); //ERROR:'object' does not contain 'ToUpper'
```

Comment: What's `Close()` and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: #1 is not a problem with `var`, it's a problem with you putting a `string` in an `object` and expecting to call `string` methods on it. #2 is just you trying to call a method that doesn't exist. What's the problem?

Comment: That's not limitation of var keyword but instead your understanding of var keyword. Both errors makes perfect sense.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what "var" means. "var" means "replace var with the compile-time type of the right hand side".  The compile-time type of obj is object, so this is the same as `object name = obj`, and you can't call `ToUpper` on something of type `object`. You are probably thinking that `var` and `dynamic` mean the same thing but they do not mean anything even close to the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I feel your question isn't clear but..

Since all types are derived from `Object` class, when you say `object obj="mukesh"`, `obj` will be `object`, not `string`.

That's why when you say `var name = obj;`, `name` will be `object` because `obj` is an `object` (it can not know what kind of variable you store in it).

When you say `var string_value = "mukesh";`, `string_value` will be `string` (which is clear). And `String` class doesn't have a method called `Close()`.

For example;

```
var obj = "mukesh";
string sTest = obj.ToUpper();
```

Works perfectly, because `var` looks `"mukesh"` and it says:

> "Hey! This is a string, so compiler should make obj as a string type"

Answer (score 0):

`var` it's  an implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type. The following two declarations of `i` are functionally equivalent:

```
var i = 10; // implicitly typed
int i = 10; //explicitly typed
```

so if you don't have a close method on your object the intelisense  will determine this